# for loop is executing only once

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to obtain the following output but I am getting only first character i.e. loop is executing only once while the code is correct. How to resolve this issue?

```
input : chirag hello bye
output : chb
```

Code:

```
public class PrintFirstLetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("input");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        String st=sc.next();

        char[] ch = st.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {       
            if((i==0&&ch[i] !=' ')||(ch[i] !=' '&&ch[i-1]==' '))
                System.out.print(ch[i]);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read the documentation of Scanner.next(). And of the Scanner class in general.

Comment: I suggest firing up a debugger in what editor/IDE you are using, and step through the code and see what happens.

Comment: I wouldn't trust `sc.next()` is returning the expected phrase.

Comment: First debuging step: print value of st...

Answer (score 3):

You have input taken as `String st=sc.next()` which takes in the string till a space is encountered. Hence, only the first word gets stored in the String st. Try changing the line to `String st=sc.nextLine()` which will work.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just try

st.length();

it also returns the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the for loop. the problem is in input method that is

```
next()
```

method takes only single word as input. for multiword input you need to use

```
nextLine()
```

method. You can confirm it by printing the String st. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

as stated above you should use nextLine(); instead of next();
you can also use trim() to remove spaces. 
a simple implementation :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintFirstLetter {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("input :");
String input = sc .nextLine();
String[] words = input.split(" ");
for (String s: words)
{
    s=s.trim();
    System.out.println("output : " + s.charAt(0));
 } 
}
}
```